# MVC - Is it possible to send an array from a .ashx.cs file to a controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to know if it it possible to add all the request files' paths into an array and to send it to my controller to insert into my database.

What I mean is this:

```
private void UploadWholeFile(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        var file = context.Request.Files[i];

        var fullPath = StorageRoot + Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

        file.SaveAs(fullPath);

        string fullName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        statuses.Add(new FilesStatus(fullName, file.ContentLength, fullPath));

        //For example here add the fullpath into a variable (array)
    }
}
```

On each file upload save into an array and then send the array to my controller action

Comment: You should not have an ASHX in the first place.  Send the request to the action directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller is also a class so you can create the instance of the controller class and can call the action.

For eg:

```
ControllerName objectName = new ControllerName() ;
objectName.ActionName(Parameters)
```

but the best way is to move your logic to the models and use its instance instead.

Comment: Ya I know but it was just for demonstration purpose.